# Functional programming for numerical simulation

Tags: oop, functional-programming, simulation

I'm recently interested in functional programming (FP).
However, I wonder whether simulation with FP is difficult or not.

For example, with object-oriented programming (OOP), I would assign a state to each agent (class, probably) and update their states causally. The history of states is recorded to a certain array. The history will be saved and flushed if necessary at each time period.

As I know, FP avoids mutable data so time-varying state of each agent cannot be contained in the agent.
Then, for simulations in FP, do I have to record states at each time instant to a certain array and not assign states to each agent? Then, what if I would like to see a state of a specific agent for debugging? Should I find the state in the recorded array?

Like the above, it's hard for me to think in an FP way for numerical simulation.
Honestly, OOP style looks natural for this task.

Can anybody explain some routines for writing numerical simulation codes in an FP way?

Comment: Do you haven an idea how to model stateful agents in FP? I don't think recording states in an array will be useful.

Comment: @Bergi Actually I agree with you. I would like to understand how to write a code in FP :)

Comment: I'd model each agent as an actor, a reducer over messages received by it.